# Copying the objects while debugging

Tags: eclipse, debugging

While copying the variable values in debugging mode of eclipse , we have the option Copy Variables , which we can use to copy the values stored in that object but now I observed that when I paste those in notepad , variables named Long,Integer don't give you the values instead you will get some reference numbers with the datatype.

For example : id    Short  (id=2435)

What If I also want to get the detailed tree copy of the object , when I am debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer , expand each and every tree node for the object .And then say copy variables and then only it will copy the variables you wanted for copying.

Comment: What if the Object is very Huge?? . You may have to extend the sub nodes or Objects 50 times or more than that which is not recommended. There should be good alternative which would copy entire object in detail